# Present Perfect Continuous with Present Simple in the subordinate clause

Tags: subordinate-clauses, present-simple

One, whom I don't know, posted this sentence on one Russian forum, where people study English. The sentence comes from [here](http://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/present-perfect-continuous-use.html)

- **They've been living** with his mother **while they look** for a house

Is it possible to place the subordinate clause in the Present Simple if the main clause is in the Present Perfect Continuous tense?

As far as I know this is a mistake. It should be either of the two:

1. They are living with his mother while looking for a house.
2. They were living with his mother while looking for a house.

The second appearance of the word **"they"** makes me uncomfortable too.

Comment: Idiomatic is "Someone I don't know posted this..." or "Someone, I don't know who, posted this ....". The first would mean that the poster is a stranger to you.  The second means you have no idea who the poster was.

Comment: The sentence you've given is idiomatic. Nothing wrong with mixing tenses like that, or with repeating the pronoun.  *He's been taking the bus while his car is in the shop.*

Comment: The cited example is completely natural. Your first alternative is "credible" for the same meaning, but in practice probably wouldn't occur so often. Your second alternative is obviously different, since it implies they *no longer* live with his mother.

Comment: @FumbleFingers My second sentence should mean that they moved to the house they found.

Comment: The problem I see is that *"They've been living with his mother while they look for a house"* they **look for a house** is a general thing they do. Maybe a habit. **"While"** implies a from-to. **"They've been living"** mean that at some point in the past they started living and they might still be living. How can they always look for a house while they have been living?

Comment: The present perfect continuous (has been writing) talks about how long something has been happening. So this was happening [They've been living with his mother] while they generally [look for a house
]. How?

Comment: The example of the Present Simple tense give no clue to why this can be correct.

Comment: You're simply mistaken in your understanding of how *while they look for a house* works there. For example, *I'll make us a cup of tea while you get dressed* in no way implies that "getting dressed" is something you do *habitually* or *for an extended period of time* (okay - most people *do* normally get dressed, but that's just something everyone knows, not something implied by the phrasing).

Comment: @FumbleFingers This I understand perfectly well. it means that two events happen at the same time.

Comment: ...if you wanted to emphasise the *duration of the house-seeking* (and/or the fact that this is a temporary state of affairs) rather than the fact that they've been doing this *while living with his mother*, you could perhaps do that better with *They live with his mother **while they are looking** for a house*.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56299/discussion-between-sovereignsun-and-fumblefingers).

Comment: @FF and I agree on this. I just wanted to add that the present *can* (but need not) refer to a customary action:  *She works in the city while he stays home with the kids.* One-off event:  *He is making the main course while she whips up a dessert*.

Comment: @TRomano: My first thought was "Those are good examples!" (for illustrating "habitual/one-off" contexts). But then it occurred to me that the first one could be understood as being paralleled by, say, *She's deeply religious while he's a committed atheist*. And I'm not convinced you can rule out the "contrastive" (as opposed to "simultaneous") meaning simply by saying it would require a comma.

Comment: They've been living with his mother [up to now when "I" am saying this; up to the present moment of "my" utterance] while they look for a house. One always needs a timeline. And one needs to think of the present present continuous(now) on the timeline as the moment of speaking. No one has mentioned this here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The moment of speaking:

It should be remembered that the PRESENT in present perfect continuous refers to the moment of speaking of the speaker. (Or writing).

https://ninespv.files.wordpress.com/2016/04/review-of-tenses-14-638.jpg

**They've been living with his mother** [present, where the speaker is located IN TIME or ON THE TIMELINE] while they look for a house.

That sentence is spoken by a speaker. **The action started in the past and continues at the moment of my uttering it**. Think of a line started in the past, and stopping right at the present, the moment of speaking.

The other two sentences are grammatical but they FUNCTION differently regarding the timeline.

1) They **are living** [I am in the present and so is the action]with his mother while looking for a house.

The verb /present continuous/ occurs at the  present line marker on the time.

2) They **were living** with his mother while looking for a house.

The past continuous does not continue in the present. It is finished at the line of the present on the time.

Comment: Impressive, yet, does my first sentence imply the same meaning as the initial sentence?

Comment: So i can say: We have been speaking about it while we drive home. And it will be correct?

Comment: @SovereignSun Your first question under my answer: No, the two sentences are different. Your second question under my answer: Yes, it is correct to write/say: We've been speaking about it while we drive home.  Trick question for you: What does the use of the present perfect continuous imply in your question? :)

Comment: I have no idea. I still can't understand any of this.

Comment: @SovereignSun The answer to my question regarding your question about: We've been speaking about it while we drive  home = ***You are still driving home***. You are talking to someone about that, probably on a cell  phone, iPad or other device. See? :) At the time you say it, it is still occurring (the driving home). Look at the timeline. In order to understand tenses in English (if you speak a language that doesn't have them), you have to imagine yourself on that timeline. Ask yourself: Where is the action occurring as I stand at the present time on that timeline.